# Possibly to change opacity or color between frames in Plotly animation?

Tags: r, plotly

Using the Plotly animation example, this works to modify the opacity overall

```
library(plotly)
library(gapminder)

gap <- gapminder
gap$opa <- 0.5

p <- gap %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~gdpPercap, 
    y = ~lifeExp, 
    size = ~pop, 
    color = ~continent, 
    frame = ~year, 
    opacity = ~opa,
    text = ~country, 
    hoverinfo = "text",
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'markers'
  ) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(
      type = "log"
    )
  )

p
```

But what I would like to do is have the opacity change (or color) between frames so that I can hide data points before a certain frame but this doesn't work:

```
library(plotly)
library(gapminder)

gap <- gapminder
gap$opa <- ifelse(gap$year < 1970, 0, 1)

p <- gap %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~gdpPercap, 
    y = ~lifeExp, 
    size = ~pop, 
    color = ~continent, 
    frame = ~year, 
    opacity = ~opa,
    text = ~country, 
    hoverinfo = "text",
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'markers'
  ) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(
      type = "log"
    )
  )

p
```

Thanks!

Edit* er title, was supposed to say "possible"

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to create an list using the range of the start and end year, then set the opacity proportionate to how far along the timeline you are.

```
start = 1952
end = 2007

list_length = length(seq(start, end))
opa <- vector(mode="list", length = list_length)
names(opa) <- c(seq(start, end))

# sets opacity between 0 and 1
for (year in c(seq(1, list_length))){
    opa[[year]] <- year / list_length
}
```

Then you can call the corresponding opacity using the year variable passed through each frame.

```
> opa[['1952']]
[1] 0.01785714
```

I'm guessing you're doing this example: https://plot.ly/r/animations/